# split list of list inside column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column:

| A |
| --- |
| "[[a,b,c,d]],[[e,f,g,h]],[[i,j,k,l]]" |

I would like:

| A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [a,b,c,d] | [e,f,g,h] | [i,j,k,l] |

I tried to do it my self with the following command:

`df.A.str.strip("[").str.split(']],', expand=True).add_prefix('A_')`

It doesn't work since i still have "]]" at the end of my last column

Comment: Try this: `df['A'].str[1:-1].str.split("\],\[", expand=True).add_prefix('A_')` or `str[2:-2]` depending if `"` is part of the string

Comment: no, its three columns. please provide the exact input in your question

Comment: Works better with str [2:-2] but i have only 1 column in output with :
'a, b, c, d]], [[e, f, g, h]], [[i, j, k, l']

Comment: df.A.values = array(['[[0.09355853497982025, 0.5229207277297974, 0.42043834924697876, 0.6298644542694092]], [[0.4478369355201721, 0.028646565973758698, 0.6494182348251343, 0.24228781461715698]], [[0.2548714876174927, 0.01043354719877243, 0.6748797297477722, 0.25291895866394043]]',
       'nan',
       '[[0.525579571723938, 0.5073766112327576, 0.7586337924003601, 0.6093847155570984]], [[0.8084242343902588, 0.47493621706962585, 0.9984089732170105, 0.5662120580673218]]',
       '[[0.5981752276420593, 0.25098392367362976, 0.8610931634902954, 0.5221621990203857]]',
       'nan'], dtype=object)

Comment: df.loc[0,A]='[[0.09355853497982025, 0.5229207277297974, 0.42043834924697876, 0.6298644542694092]], [[0.4478369355201721, 0.028646565973758698, 0.6494182348251343, 0.24228781461715698]], [[0.2548714876174927, 0.01043354719877243, 0.6748797297477722, 0.25291895866394043]]'

Comment: you just have to add a space to the split seperator `"\], \["`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['A'].str[1:-1].str.split("\], \[", expand=True).add_prefix('A_')
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)